# inotify - maintaining watch through log rollover

Tags: inotify

I have a `inotifywait` on `syslog`. It works without issue until the log rolls over.

Although the same filename is used, the new file is a new file and `inotify` loses its reference.

How do we compensate for this to maintain the watch through the log rollover?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the containing directory to detect and respond to the creation of the new file after roll-over?

Comment: @AndyDalton That'a good suggestion but instead I have a `function setup` to init the watch and monitor the file events I'm interested in. On the  `MOVE_SELF` event I make a recursive call to the `setup `function. That might be a spectacularly bad solution but I'm just a hobbyist so no real damage. A regular restart of the service should ward off disaster but I'm interested in what will happen. How does bash handle recursion?

Comment: You could restart your `iwatch` as part of the log rollover. `man logrotate logrotate.conf`.

Comment: @waltinator Oh yeah! With the `postrotate` property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restart your `iwatch` as part of the log rollover. `man logrotate logrotate.conf`.

**added by OP:**

The installed `logrotate.conf` (as of Ubuntu 20.04) is configured to read the contents of `/etc/logrotate.d`. In that directory, the `syslog` configuration is in `rsyslog`. In that file there is a `syslog` section as below which I modified as indicated.

```
 /var/log/syslog
 {
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
       <MY MONITOR SCRIPT HERE> 
    endscript
 }
```